# Android Pop up with arrow head

Tags: android, popup

I need to create a pop up menu when I click on a button. The pop up should focused on what i clicked (I used to call that type of pop ups as arrow head pop ups).

Here is the link to a sample image:

[image: Sample image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per my understanding, you are trying to create `Quick Actions bar`. The following links should help you:

http://web.archive.org/web/20170710025043/http://www.xoriant.com/blog/android/android-ui-design-pattern-quick-action-bar.html

http://www.londatiga.net/it/how-to-create-quickaction-dialog-in-android/

Comment: Can you please post me a more simple example.Pleaseeeee'''