# Show android pop up window on click of imageview and place it near to imageview

Tags: android

I want popup window like this to be shown next to image view supporting every device and tablet. I have tried using showAtLocation() but still not satisfied with popup location.

[image: Show pop up window like this..]

Comment: not satisfied?  why?  it looks OK to me

Comment: What about the image you shared? is it your output or you want to achieve that? And share the code what you done??

Comment: Here is a same kind of question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10244032/android-pop-up-with-arrow-head

Comment: I want to show like this..its not what I am getting

Answer (score 1):

You need to put a RelativeLayout on top of your existing layout and position the popup within it.

Have a look at how [android-tooltips](https://github.com/rharter/android-tooltips) or [supertooltips](https://github.com/nhaarman/supertooltips) do it.